# Will Amazon EC2 still charge me if I stop all instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I have terminated all my instances in AWS, but didn't receive any information that my service of the

> m1.small

was shut down.

I was wondering if I will still be charged by the AWS?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be charged for the time that those instances were up.

You won't be charged any more for those instances if you have terminated them.

If you want to be absolutely certain and will not need the AWS services anymore, you can always close your AWS account.

Answer (score 0):

> Pricing is per instance-hour consumed for each instance, from the time an instance is launched until it is terminated or stopped. Each partial instance-hour consumed will be billed as a full hour.
>
> [Amazon Pricing Details](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)

When it is terminated or stopped, there will be no charge.